# Wired PC/Wireless network printer

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer, hp

So exactly how do I set my wireless printer up to work with a PC with ethernet connection. I tried a couple of days ago and it wasn't automatic. The PC couldn't find the printer. Do I have to do some manual settings on the printer for the PC to find it on the network even though it's shared?

Comment: All my wireless printers *just work™* when following the instructions included with the printer. Perhaps you *did something wrong™*? Since you haven't provided any information about the printer, or the "PC", the answer is a pineapple

Comment: have you joined the printer to your wifi network?

Comment: Well it's my church who uses a managed wifi console on cox business internet. It's a dell desktop pc using an ethernet connection and I'm trying to connect the hp printer(officejet 6978) over wifi. The printer needs to be wireless as there will be several devices that need to connect to this printer.

Comment: Yeah Frank, I did that first and then tried to connect the desktop to it thru the HP printer assistant. Is that the wrong order?

Comment: if everything is proper, yes. does your wifi have a feature enabled called "AP Isolation" or "Client Isolation" or something like that enabled? the feature is designed to prevent users in a coffee shop (or church) from trying to hack each other by making them unable to reach anything except the internet, and blocks devices on the wifi from seeing other devices on the network (and vice-versa). personally, i have a wired connection to my printer, because I'm sick of the thing not working on the 2 occasions I have per year to print something, and removing wifi from the mix is more reliable.

Comment: whst happens when you try to access the printer using a web browser?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try giving us the IP addresses of the printer and a PC. They may be on different subnets, with the router preventing access.